# Error : avformat_open_input: Protocol not found : -1330794744

Tags: android, ffmpeg, vitamio

I am building an android stream player using Vitamio.
Here is my codes:

```
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    path = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vic5gj2qXKg";
    mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);

    mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    mVideoView.requestFocus();

    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
        }
    });
```

But it returns ERROR:

> avformat_open_input: Protocol not found : -1330794744
>   error (1, -1330794744)

I think this error is related to FFMpeg for Vitamio.
Who can solve this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It appears when ffmpeg does not support streaming format, or not initialized by "avformat_network_init()"

See if you can find whether Vitamio supports network format or not, or some function to initialize.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube videos links can be play via only Youtube Android  Player API. Download Jar from here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/